# Angular 2/4 authentication to Django rest_framework_jwt using custom model

Tags: django, angular, authentication, model, jwt

How are you eveyone.
I am developing Angular 4 website using Django Backend server.
To use JWT for authentication, I am using rest_framework_jwt module of Django.
Also I am using custom model for authentication(there are some reason for that)
I tried authentication using default authentication model with rest_framework-jwt module and It works well.
But I am not sure how to use custom model for authentication with rest_framework_jwt in Django.
Example code or link will be big help! :)
Thanks for your consideration.

*) Following is what I have done without restframework. and I would like to convert it using restframeworkjwt

```
def post_signup(request):

        if request.method == 'POST':
            json_data = json.loads(request.body)
            user = User(fullname=json_data['fullname']
                        ,email=json_data['email']
                        ,password=json_data['password']
                        ,right= 'user'
                        ,status= 'pending')
            try:
                result = user.save()
                return JsonResponse({'status':'ok'})
            except IntegrityError , err:
                return JsonResponse({'status':'no','message':str(err)})
def post_login(request):

        if request.method == 'POST':
            json_data = json.loads(request.body)


            try:
                user = User.objects.get(email=json_data['email'], password=json_data['password'])
                return JsonResponse({'status':'ok'})
            except User.DoesNotExist :
                return JsonResponse({'status':'no','message':'Email or Password not exists'})
```

Comment: if you have already use custom auth model, all must work fine. Or you have some troubles?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have already implemented simple authentication without restframework, and I would like to convert authentication method to using rest_framework_jwt. I added code what I have done